# Remove some auto generated text from a heading with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using uncode theme and I have a page heading that is showing 'Archive: Portfolio'

I want to remove the 'Archive:' bit from that heading.

In the source it looks like this:

`<h1 class="header-title h1"><span>Archives: Projects</span></h1>`

I have tried removing Archive from all the page titles with Yoast SEO plugin but it is still showing.

Is there a way to remove that word with javascript maybe does anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be wary in removing it via javascript. It seems to me that adding a piece of text somewhere in the code's execution, and then removing it on the client-side smells like ["contrived complexity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell#Common_code_smells).

Take a look at the [wordpress template hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/), and manually search for the template file that's rendering the `Archives:` string of text.

I'd start with `archive.php`, and then fall my way up through other `archive-*.php` pages, then to `taxonomy.php` `category.php`, and so on.

[image: WordPress Template Hierarchy]

If you're comfy in the command line, you might also consider grepping for the string: `grep -r /path/to/wp/theme "Archive:"` and sifting through the results to find the template file(s) with that on one of their lines.

But if you insist on removing the string via javascript, you might try dropping something like this at the bottom of the `<body>`, via a function in `functions.php`:

```
function remove_archive_text_via_js() {
    if (is_archive()) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var archiveHeaders = document.getElementsByClassName('header-title');
            for (i = 0, headerCount = archiveHeaders.length; i < headerCount; i++) {
                var replacedText = archiveHeaders[i].textContent.replace('Archives: ', '');
                archiveHeaders[i].textContent = replacedText;
            }
        </script>
    <?php }
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'remove_archive_text_via_js');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Normally I'd be fine doing this, however the site is built on the uncode theme and there are no page templates as such. It's all built with theme options within the WP admin area instead so I'm not really familiar.

Comment: Added a js option, as well. ;)

Comment: not familiar at all with command line but that sure sounds like a useful tool as I'm often trawling through searching for things in template files!

Comment: As the pages are all dynamically generated, I'd be adding that to the footer file so it would end up on all pages (which is no huge deal as I don't want Archive: anywhere). However just wondering if there is a way to target a page with it, adding it as some sort of function maybe?

Comment: Sure thing. Wrap a php block around it that looks something like `<?php if (is_archive()) { /* the js /* }`   https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive

Comment: It works a treat BTW but you already knew that, thanks! So I have it just in my global footer file at the moment. If anyway to just target a single page with it or move this to my functions (is that possible? sorry I'm clearly not well versed in js!)

Comment: Will put a refactoring of it into the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('header-title h1');

var innerSpan = elem[0].getElementsByTagName('span');
innerSpan[0].innerHTML = innerSpan[0].innerHTML.replace('Archives: ', 'jsfiddle');
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/orcadj3u/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Where would I put this please?

Comment: In the foot of the template where the page resides. Make sure you wrap it in javascript tags:
<script language="javascript">
...code here...
</script>

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
 $( "h1 span" ).each(function( index ) {
  var newtext = $(this).text().replace("Archives: ", " ");
  $(this).html(newtext);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="header-title h1"><span>Archives: Projects</span></h1><br>
<h1 class="header-title h1"><span>Archives: Solutions</span></h1><br>
<h1 class="header-title h1"><span>Archives: Yozgat</span></h1><br>
<h1 class="header-title h1"><span>Archives: Turkey</span></h1><br>
```